# Replacing Any Character with Dots

Tags: sql, oracle, replace, character

I need to replace any character (following, say, 15th position) with two dots (for example). What's the function that should be used? "Substr" just cuts, "replace" searches for a specific string (and I need any key(s)...
Thanks

Comment: Please give example output you required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do 2 things,
1- use Reg expression as explained here:
https://community.oracle.com/thread/895398?tstart=0

2- You can use your substr function and just cut it from 1-15 and concat it with two dots.